# Building Nuxt in Docker takes 22 minutes, but 2 minutes outside of docker?

Tags: docker, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app that takes a few minutes (2-4) to build `nuxt build`.

I've moved it into docker, trying a few different guides (like [this](https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/koyeb/), or [this](https://dev.to/fbjorn/reducing-docker-image-size-of-a-nuxt-ssr-application-40oe)).

For some reason, building in docker is taking 20+ minutes?

The only difference is I'm building for M1 using `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16.13.1-slim`.

Does anyone have experience building Nuxt in docker and know what may cause this?

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16.13.1-slim as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --frozen-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=false

ARG NODE_ENV
ARG GIT_COMMIT
ARG BUILD_VERSION
COPY .env.${NODE_ENV} .

RUN yarn build

RUN rm -rf node_modules && \
  NODE_ENV=production yarn install \
  --prefer-offline \
  --pure-lockfile \
  --non-interactive \
  --production=true

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16.13.1-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app  .

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Comment: Do you have a Dockerfile or any other details for a [mcve]?  (Are you trying to use Node in an isolated Docker container to build an application that lives only on your host?  That's a process known to be slow on MacOS.)

Comment: Not an expert in Docker but isn't there a principle of threads/memory/alike to allocate to the whole container? Probably what is slowing things down.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks - added. @Kissu: [`By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler allows.`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)

Comment: I have an M1 too and I have the same problem, because you are using amd64 architecture, if you are using docker desktop client you may have seen the message: Image may have poor performance, or fail, if run via emulation.

This can become a nightmare with the waiting time. I stopped using it and when using CI/CD tools on external services, this issue doesn't appear. I have given up on docker for building.  If you want to have a different version of the node on your local have a look at nvm this does the trick for me.